# Least square approximation where X vector is given.

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I want to find a curve of the form $y = a + b \sqrt{x}$ that best fits the points: $(3, 1.5)$, $(7, 2.5)$ and $(10, 3)$ by substituting the $x$ vector $= \sqrt{x}$

My understanding of the process to find the least squares approximation was that the $x$ vector contained the unknown variables so you could use guassian elimination to find the variables $a$,$b$ from: $A^t A x = A^t B$ but I am unsure how this would work when the $x$ vector is already given and you want to find $a$,$b$ still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points are given as $(x_i, y_i)$ and one has the unknowns $a$, $b$ which need to be optimized:
$$
y_i = a + b \sqrt{x_i} \quad (i \in \{1,2,3\}) \iff \\
A x = y
$$
with
$$
x = (a, b)^t \in \mathbb{R}^2, \quad y = (y_i) \in \mathbb{R}^3, \quad A = (a_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 2}, \quad a_{i1} = 1, \quad a_{i2} = \sqrt{x_i} \quad (i \in \{1,2,3\})
$$
gives
$$
A x = y \iff 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & \sqrt{x_1} \\
1 & \sqrt{x_2} \\
1 & \sqrt{x_3}
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a \\
b
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
$A$ is overspecified (more equations than unknowns), so the matrix is not square and can not be inverted. 
However
$$
A^t A x = A^t y \Rightarrow x = (A^tA)^{-1} A^t y
$$
can be shown to give a solution with minimal error in the $2$-norm, which is the standard, Euclidean norm.

I get $x = (-0.31587, 1.05405)^t$ which gives $Ax = (1.5098, 2.4729, 3.0173)^t$ and $\delta = \lVert Ax-y \rVert = 0.033639$, which seems reasonable.

[image: square root fit]

Graph of $f(x) = a + b \sqrt{x}=−0.31587+ 1.05405\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: I was able to follow and get similar answers but I'm not sure I follow the last statement δ=∥Ax−y∥=0.033639. Could you please explain what the last statement concludes (apart from being the result)? I just haven't seen that before

Comment: $Ax$ applies the found coefficients $x=(a,b)$ to the data stored in $A$, the resulting $Ax=y'$ is the vector of $y$ coordinates $y'_i = f(x_1)$ of the found interpolation curve $f$. So $Ax-y = y'-y$ is the difference vector between interpolation and targets $y_i$. The norm $\delta$ is the length of that difference vector and a single value measure of the interpolation quality. $\delta =0$ would indicate a perfect fit.

Comment: And the claim of the least squares fit is that you will not find a better $x$, meaning having a smallet $\delta$.

Comment: Sorry if this seems trivial but can I conclude that given that the norm is close to 0 I have a good fit and can use the resulting coefficients from x=(−0.31587,1.05405) and can be used to give the curve that best fits the given points? So it would be y = -0.31587 + 1.05405*sqrt(x) ?

Comment: Those coefficients are the best choice by the method. The givem graph was drawn with those and you can barely see the points devisting from the red line.